# Simple example using Erlang for https post

Tags: ssl, https, erlang

I have found quote a few examples of using erlang with ssl (via rpc) and http get's etc. But I am having a hard time finding an example of posting data to an ssl endpoint via erlang. Does anybody know of a simple example that I am missing?

I think I figured it out. I had the arguments wrong. This is what I ended-up with for a post:

```
httpc:request(post, {"https://localhost:2840", [], [], ["Test"]}, [], [])
```

Appears to be working. But my server is crashing now. So, maybe not.

Comment: perhaps this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2886521/how-do-i-do-an-https-request-with-erlang

Comment: I found that but it's not for a post and I could not find in the documentation how the body needs to be set.

Comment: And this also appears to be outdated as http has been replaced by httpc. But thank you for the response.

Comment: yeah, sorry about that. What were your problems using httpc? Could you update your question with what you have tried?

Comment: What did the server log say?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You'll need to start ssl and inets before you send the request. Depending on the type of data you're trying to post, it'll have to be formatted differently. My example shows urlencoded data

```
ssl:start(),
application:start(inets),
httpc:request(post, 
    {"https://postman-echo.com/post", [], 
    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "example=here&foo=bar"
    }, [], []).
```

A JSON request would look like

```
ssl:start(),
application:start(inets),
httpc:request(post,
    {"https://postman-echo.com/post", [],
    "application/json",
    "{'example':'here', 'foo':'bar'}"
    }, [], []).
```